# Ruby on Rails 301 redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, seo, actioncontroller

I added slugs to some of the models, but because of SEO I need to do 301 redirection from old links:
old:

```
http://host.com/foo/1
```

new:

```
http://host.com/foo/foo_slug
```

question:
how to implement 301 redirection in this case?
and is it possible to implement 301 redirection from uppercased link? Like this:

```
http://host.com/foo/FOO_SLUG -> http://host.com/foo/foo_slug
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to redirect with status 301 by adding this to your controller action:

```
redirect_to "http://host.com/foo/foo_slug", :status => 301
```

See the API documentation for [`redirect_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) for details.

And there should be no problem with redirecting upper-cased URLs to lowercased versions, although this may be better handled by something at the HTTP server layer such as Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rules.

Comment: .. or the nginx config. passengers seems to be more popular on nginx

Comment: Thank you for answer, also, Rails 3 allows to create 301 redirects directly from routes.rb, is it better to do it in controller or in the routes?

Comment: In your case I think you will have to do it in the controller action, since I assume you are going to be looking up the slug from a database? If so, the code to look up a record and find its slug can only occur within a controller action, not within `routes.rb`

Comment: I just need to check is there in params old `:id`, and if yes redirect to instance_path with correct slugged `:id`?

Comment: Right, but in order to translate the `:id` into the corrected slug, you have to run a database query right? If so, it must be done in a controller, not in routes

Comment: One more question - what is the better way to handle 301 redirection if this case: `http://host.com/bars/:id////////(random number of slashes)` -> `301` -> `http://host.com/bars/:id`?

Comment: I would think that the same `redirect_to` call would be able to handle it, as long as your Rails routes correctly route the URL with a lot of slashes to your controller route containing the redirect.

Answer (score 2):

For 301 redirection write this code in your controller:

headers["Status"] = "301 Moved Permanently"

redirect_to  "http://host.com/foo/foo_slug"   # in your case

And for second question, use capitalise or down case if you mentioned hardcode url.

Otherwise use ruby interpolation by putting whole url in string

Comment: Rather than hard-code the `Status` header, why not just pass `:status => 301` and let Rails handle formatting that header (see my answer for an example)