# Redirect all links from previous website to new website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

My application was built with WordPress. After 4 years I migrated from **WordPress** to **Ruby on Rails `4.2.4`**.

My google page score is very good and I would like to redirect my WordPress links to my new setup (Ruby on Rails). My Ruby on rails applications link structure is different then WordPress.

*PS: I still on same domain*

*WP Link Structure:*
`my-website.com/year/month/day/Post-Title`

*Ruby on Rails Link Structure:*
`my-website.com/p/Post-Title`

How can I **permanently move** *old* links to my new links and have **SEO** in mind.

*I am basically doing this for **SEO***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872233/ruby-on-rails-301-redirection

Comment: @Iceman Yeah this would work if the links were not on Wordpress. All the links are outside of the application/controller and its not just one redirect, its about 2000 redirects

Comment: Hey not used WP in a while, but you should check this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/

Comment: Also checkout this post: http://madlemmings.com/2015/08/10/how-redirect-wordpress-page-plugins/

Comment: Thanks @oreoluwa These would work if my Wordpress application wouldn't be gone when migrating process was done.

Comment: then i think the `.htaccess` option would be your best bet IMHO! Although it also has its own separate considerations!

Comment: Thanks @oreoluwa Yeah I was also thinking about `.htaccess `. What considerations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect from old links structure to another, while keeping only a part of the original URLs, you must capture this part and use it in the target URL

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+?/.+?/.+?/(.+)$ /p/$1 [R,L]
```

The first three `.+?` match year, month and day. The final `(.+)` captures the title, so it can be reused in the target URL `/p/$1`.

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)). *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Comment: Thanks @Olaf. I use `Ruby on Rails 4.2.4` and `phusion passenger`. Can I add it to a `. htaccess` and if you are familiar with it, where to add the `.htaccess`.

Comment: If there are already some RewriteRules, you may insert this rule below `RewriteEngine on` and before any other rules. If this doesn't work for some reason, edit your question and show the current .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf. Currently I dont have `.htaccess`. One question in your answer you wrote: **To redirect from one site to another**. I don't redirect from one domain to another domain, I want to redirect **my old Wordpress urls** to my **new Ruby on rails url** In same domain. Does your solution still work?

Comment: Yes it does, just create the .htacces files with the given updated directives.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Olaf :)